# how to track the number of pwa installations

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I'm using the

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e => {
  e.userChoice.then(choiceResult => {
    ga('send', 'event', 'A2H', choiceResult.outcome);
    alert('AAAAAAAAAAAAAa',choiceResult.outcome)
  });
});
```

but this event not work with event default of pwa, only work with one button custom generating `deferredPrompt.prompt();`
what i can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any PWA experience, but I found these two resources that may help.

#### [1. window.addEventListener('appinstalled', function() { });](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/appinstalled_event)

```js
window.addEventListener('appinstalled', function() { 
  console.log('Thank you for installing our app!'); 
});
// or 
window.onappinstalled = function() { 
  console.log('Thank you for installing our app!'); 
};
```

#### [2. this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWRdBywm4Zo&feature=youtu.be)

I wanted to learn more about PWAs last week and stumbled across this youtube video. It has some good info. It talks about deferring the event object from `'beforeinstallprompt'` so you can use it later in your own "Install" prompt.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, to resolve just using this function
`window.onappinstalled = function(ev) {}`